# Jersey 1.x is replacing the plus symbol with a space symbol. How can I prevent this?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-1.0

I'm using the jersey client to send a query param to my jersey server.  This is the query: `?sort=id+ASC`

But in my code that retrieves this query param, `return uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("sort");`, this value evaluates to `id ASC`.  Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: A query string of `?sort=id+ASC` _does_ represent a parameter value of "id ASC" because query strings are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  If you want to send a parameter value of "id+ASC" then you'd have to use a query string of `?sort=id%2BASC`

Comment: @IanRoberts I see.  I guess I can just live with it.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from @IanRoberts's suggestion, you could make use of the [`@Encoded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Encoded.html) annotation to get to the original undecoded value of you parameter (by default Jersey decodes the values and that's why `id+ASC` becomes `id ASC` in your code).

The following example retrieves the decoded value as for the default behavior:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response test(@QueryParam("sort") String sort) {
    // sort is "id ASC"
    return Response.ok().entity(sort).build();
}
```

To change the behavior you just add `@Encoded`:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response test(@QueryParam("sort") @Encoded String sort) {
    // sort is "id+ASC"
    return Response.ok().entity(sort).build();
}
```

Comment: @tieTYT: Yes. I've done a quick search to see in what version it was added and it seems it's there since 1.4: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Encoded.html